# Counting occurrences of words within an inputted string in c

Tags: c, word-count

I'm currently struggling with counting the occurrences of the words within an inputted string. I believe it is just my logic that is off but I've been scratching my head for a while and I've just hit a wall.

The problems I'm currently yet to solve are:

1. With longer inputs the ends of the string is sometimes cut off.
2. Incrementing the counter for each word when repeated

I know the code has things that may not be the most ideal way for it to work but I'm fairly new to C so any pointers are really helpful.

**To sum it up I'm looking for pointers to help solve the issues I'm facing above**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 1000

int main(void) {
    int i,j,isUnique,uniqueLen;
    char word[MAX_WORDS];
    char words[200][30];
    char uniqueWords[200][30];
    int count[200];
    char *p = strtok(word, " ");
    int index=0;

    //read input until EOF is reached
    scanf("%[^EOF]", word);

    //initialize count array
    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    //convert lower case letters to upper
    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z') {
            word[i] = word[i] - 32;
        }
    }

    //Split work string into an array and save each token into the array words
    p = strtok(word, " ,.;!\n");
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(words[index], p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ,.;!\n");
        index++;
    }

    /* 
    Check each string in the array word for occurances within the uniqueWords array. If it is unique then 
    copy the string from word into the unique word array. Otherwise the counter for the repeated word is incremented.
    */ 
    uniqueLen = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        isUnique = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < index; j++) {
            if (strcmp(uniqueWords[j],words[i])==0) {   
                isUnique = 0;
                break;
            }
            else {
            }
        }
        if (isUnique) {
            strcpy(uniqueWords[uniqueLen], words[i]);
            count[uniqueLen] += 1;
            uniqueLen++;
        }
        else {
        } 
    }

    for (i = 0; i < uniqueLen; i++) {
        printf("%s => %i\n", uniqueWords[i],count[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `char word[MAX_WORDS]; char *p = strtok(word, " ");` Why are you trying to `strtok` an unintialised variable? That is Undefined Behaviour and can lead to program crashes or other unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: okay so user3121023, this is something i found looking for solutions. using the suggestion of `scanf("%999[^\n]", word);` would this scan across multiple lines or until just the \n is found?

Comment: kaylum is there a different way to split a string which im assigning through an input? ive been looking around and this seemed to pop up a lot so was assuming this is the way to do it.

Comment: `for (j = 0; j < index; j++) { if (strcmp(uniqueWords[j],words[i])==0)` That is also Undefined Behaviour. `index` is the length of the `words` array but not the `uniqueWords` array.

Comment: "*is there a different way to split a string*". Using `strtok` is fine. The problem is that the first `strtok` call is done *before* `word` has been read. So `word` contains garbage at that point and the `strtok` may end up reading past the end of the array into invalid memory. The `strtok` calls after that don't have that problem.

Comment: okay, going to take this away and rework things :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code i ended up using, this turned out to be mainly an issue with using the scanf function. Placing it in a while loop made it much easier to edit words as inputted.

Thankyou for all the help :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>



int main(void) {

    // Create all variables 
    int i, len, isUnique, index;
    char word[200];
    char uniqueWords[200][30];
    int count[200];

    // Initialize the count array
    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    // Set the value for index to 0
    index = 0;

    // Read all words inputted until the EOF marker is reached
    while (scanf("%s", word) != EOF) {

        /* 
        For each word being read if the characters within it are lowercase 
        then each are then incremented into being uppercase values.
        */
        for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z') {
                word[i] = word[i] - 32;
            }
        }
        /* 
        We use len to find the length of the word being read. This is then used
        to access the final character of the word and remove it if it is not an
        alphabetic character.
        */
        len = strlen(word);
        if (ispunct(word[len - 1]))
            word[len - 1] = '\0';

        /*
        The next part removes the non alphabetic characters from within the words.
        This happens by incrementing through each character of the word and by 
        using the isalpha and removing the characters if they are not alphabetic
        characters.
        */
        size_t pos = 0;
        for (char *p = word; *p; ++p)
            if (isalpha(*p))
                word[pos++] = *p;
        word[pos] = '\0';

        /* 
        We set the isUnique value to 1 as upon comparing the arrays later we 
        change this value to 0 to show the word is not unique.
        */
        isUnique = 1;
        /* 
        For each word through the string we use a for loop when the counter i 
        is below the index and while the isUnique value is 1.
        */
        for (i = 0; i < index && isUnique; i++)
        {
            /* 
            Using the strcmp function we are able to check if the word in 
            question is in the uniqueWords array. If it is found we then 
            change the isUnique value to 0 to show that the value is not
            unique and prevent the loop happening again.
            */
            if (strcmp(uniqueWords[i], word) == 0)
                isUnique = 0;
        }

        /* If word is unique then add it to the uniqueWords list
        and increment index. Otherwise increment occurrence 
        count of current word.
        */
        if (isUnique)
        {   
            strcpy(uniqueWords[index], word);
            count[index]++;
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            count[i - 1]++;
        }
    }
    /*
    For each item in the uniqueWords list we iterate through the words
    and print them out in the correct format with the word and the following count of them.
    */
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        printf("%s => %d\n", uniqueWords[i], count[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used this in the code and passed a full string into the program and had a correct output. Therefore, reading an entire list of words as it is within a while loop?

Comment: Yes I missed the EOF comparison, nevermind the comment.

Comment: awesome thankyou :) wanted to make sure it wasnt a fault on my end which could happen also

Comment: A problem you can face is buffer oveflow in case one word has more than 999 chars, maybe unlikely, but using a width specifier is safer `"%999s"`. One thing I've came to realise is that we can't trust the user to make sensible decisions ;)

Comment: I can definitely see this being an issue. However, decided not to take this into account as the specification i was given said it would only be tested with limits lower than what could cause this issue thankfully... dont think i can cope with looking at this code again xD

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are facing some requirements, but for all it's limitations in terms of standard library functions, C does have one that would make your job much easier, [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr), **e.g.**:

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W4j3dMbTK)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  const char str[] = "stringstringdstringdstringadasstringipoistring";
  const char* substr = "string";
  const char* orig = str;
  const char* temp = substr;


  int length = 0;
  while(*temp++){length++;} // length of substr

  int count = 0;
  char *ret = strstr(orig, substr);

  while (ret != NULL){
    count++; 
    //check next occurence  
    ret = strstr(ret + length, substr);   
  }
  printf("%d", count);
}
```

The output should be `6`.

Regarding [user3121023's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68621088/counting-occurrences-of-words-within-an-inputted-string-in-c/68621447#comment121272409_68621088), `scanf("%999[^\n]", word);` parses all characters until it finds a `\n` or it reaches the width limit, and I agree `fgets ( word, sizeof word, stdin);` is better.